# Track emails from outlook to multiple entities

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a requirement to track emails from outlook to multiple entities. For example, when an email arrives, outlook user should be able to track email from Set Regarding to an Account, but also connect this record to a campaign. Could this functionality be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft is planning to launch this multiple regarding feature, and it’s announced recently. It’s still in public preview and general availability date is not finalized, till then this feature will not be Production ready.

Read more: [Associate activities with multiple related records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/release-plan/2023wave2/data-platform/associate-activities-multiple-related-records?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422)

> Activity records like emails, appointments, tasks, and calls can be associated to additional activity participants (parties) such as accounts, contacts, leads, and opportunities through a new partylist attribute*. Previously, it wasn't possible to associate an activity record to additional related party records. With this feature, users will be able to associate activity records with additional related parties, such as an email or meeting related to multiple cases or opportunities.
>
> *Public preview will only support email.